# CustomControl calculate own width and height - ArrangeOverride gets called with bounds.Height=0

Tags: .net, maui

I'm trying to implement a "playing card" as `ContentView` which calculates its width and height by a ratio. The ContentView's Content is a Grid with some labels. When calculating the Size of the playing card control, I need to tell the child/grid what size it can occupy. In my first attempts using `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` it looks like all my tries get ignored when setting a size. I simplified the whole code to set only the minimal size of the control but the size still gets ignored.

Noticeable `ArrangeOverride(Rect bounds)` gets called with the following parameter value `bounds = { X=0, Y=0, Width=1013, Height=0 }` . Why is the height 0? I even declared the minimum height in `OnMeasure` to 85 and there is plenty more space available. What I'm doing wrong here?

The custom control code behind:

```cs
    public partial class CardView : ContentView
    {
        private const double minWidth = 55;
        private const double minHeight = 85;
        public CardView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BackgroundColor = Colors.BlueViolet;
        }
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            //define minimum size of control
            var minSize = new Size(minWidth, minHeight);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MeasureOverride width={minSize.Width},height={minSize.Height}");
            return minSize;
        }
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Rect bounds) //bounds = { X=0, Y=0, Width=1013, Height=0 } 
        {
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, minWidth, minHeight);
            grid.WidthRequest = minWidth;
            grid.HeightRequest = minHeight;
            //grid.Arrange(rect); //results int Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"ArrangeOverride width={minWidth},height={minWidth}");
            return new Size(minWidth, minHeight);
        }
        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"OnSizeAllocated width={width},height={height}");
        }
    }
```

xaml code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CustomLayouts.CardView"
             BackgroundColor="Red">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="grid" BackgroundColor="DarkRed">
            <Label Text="1" />
        </Grid>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

[Edit] The output is as the follows:

```
OnSizeAllocated width=-1,height=-1
MeasureOverride width=55,height=85
MeasureOverride width=55,height=85
OnSizeAllocated width=1013,height=0
ArrangeOverride width=55,height=55
MeasureOverride width=55,height=85
```

The grid and cardcontrols size is with=1013 and height=0.

I created a sample repo here: https://github.com/mfe-/CustomLayoutExamples . Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: I agree it is surprising that your forcing of size in ArrangeOverride didn't propagate to the next pass. Might be a special case - I suspect "0" means "not constrained". Perhaps something in parent "knows" that the contentview gets all remaining space, so ignored the value returned by Measure. If you run the code, does the grid occupy the entire vertical height? What did MeasureOverride receive as heightConstraint? What did OnSizeAllocated see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my approach calculating the size of my control missed an important step. I need to set the `DesiredSize` in order that `ArrangeOverride` will be called with the correct values.

My code looks now like the following:

```cs
protected override Size MeasureOverride(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        var size = Size.Zero;
        //size is not set, calculate the size dynamicly
        if (WidthRequest == -1 && HeightRequest == -1)
        {
            //calculate size
            size = CalculateCardSize(
                widthConstraint == 0 ? double.PositiveInfinity : widthConstraint,
                heightConstraint == 0 ? double.PositiveInfinity : heightConstraint);
        }
        else
        {
            //if the size of the control was set for example in xaml, we use those values
            size = new Size(WidthRequest, HeightRequest);
        }
        //it looks like the desired size must be set in measureoverride
        this.DesiredSize = size;
        base.MeasureOverride(size.Width, size.Height);

        return size;
    }
```

With the above code the method `protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Rect bounds)` was called with the proper values.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue regarding measuring and layout for custom controls, which seems to cause the problems you are experiencing: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4019